# Remove key, value from JSON in nifi and send the rest JSON to next processor

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, jolt

**Input JSON**

```json
{
  "Uid": "00d44cd2-38c9-4d96-b0e8-e34a476b2be8", // to be removed
  "eventId": "00d44cd2-38c9-4d96-b0e8-e34a476b2be8",
  "clientId": "**asd",
  "customerIdHash": "1e18411a-63b2-eb11-812d-asdasd",
  "eventTimestamp": "2021-05-"
}
```

I want to remove the key `Uid` and its value then send it to the next **nifi** processor as it is.
How I can achieve this in **NIFI**?

**OutPut JSON:**

```json
{
  "eventId": "00d44cd2-38c9-4d96-b0e8-e34a476b2be8",
  "clientId": "**asd",
  "customerIdHash": "1e18411a-63b2-eb11-812d-005056a43026",
  "eventTimestamp": "2021-05-"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `remove` spec,

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Uid": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: For anyone other falling over this. You need to use the JoltTransformJSON Processor with the "chain" DSL Setting, to use the above spec.